# Pandas sort grouby groups by arbitrary condition on its contents

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Ok, this is getting ridiculous ... I've spent way too much time on something that should be trivial.

I want to group a data frame by a column, then sort the **groups** (not within the group) by some condition (in my case maximum over some column B in the group).

I expected something along these lines:

`df.groupby('A').sort_index(lambda group_content: group_content.B.max())`

I also tried:

```
groups = df.groupby('A')
maxx = gg['B'].max()
groups.sort_index(...)
```

But, of course, no `sort_index` on a group by object ..

**EDIT:**

I ended up using (almost) the solution suggested by @jezrael

```
df['max'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')
df = df.sort_values(['max', 'B'], ascending=True).drop('max', axis=1)
groups = df.groupby('A', sort=False)
```

I had to add `ascending=True` to `sort_values`, but **more** importantly `sort=False` to `groupby`, otherwise I would get the groups sort lex (A contains strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need if possible same max for some groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` for new column and then sort by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':list('aaabcc'),
         'B':[7,8,9,100,20,30]
})

df['max'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')

df = df.sort_values(['max','A'])
print (df)
   A    B  max
0  a    7    9
1  a    8    9
2  a    9    9
4  c   20   30
5  c   30   30
3  b  100  100
```

If always max values are unique use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html):

```
s = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')
df = df.iloc[s.argsort()]
print (df)
   A    B
0  a    7
1  a    8
2  a    9
4  c   20
5  c   30
3  b  100
```

Comment: Since he wants to sort the groups, and not the values `within the groups`, I think the sort should be `df.sort_values('max')`.

Comment: @IMCoins - yes, or also `.sort_values(['max','A'])` if possible some groups have same max - then sorting by both columns